# Add UIImageView, UILabel to UIStackView programmatically in Swift 4

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, swift4, uistackview

I'm trying to create a set of `UIImageView`, `UILabel` and add to `UIStackView` programmatically like so.

```
var someLetters: [Int: String] = [0:"g",1:"n",2:"d"]

let stackView1 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: createLetters(someLetters))
someScrollView.addSubview(stackView1)

func createLetters(_ named: [Int: String]) -> [UIView] {
    return named.map { name in
        let letterImage = UIImageView()
        letterImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(name.key)")

        let letterLabel = UILabel()
        letterLabel.text = name.value

        let subView = UIView()
        subView.addSubview(letterLabel)
        subView.addSubview(letterImage)

        return subView
    }
}
```

`UIStackView`s `arrangedSubviews` only accepts `UIView` as a parameter
so I created an additional `UIView` as a container of `UILabel` and `UIImageView`. No compile error but not seeing any UI elements on a screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try to add a width and height constrain. once i have also face this issue

Comment: You need to add constraint for stackView1 & tell stackView1 how it will arrange views added to it (i think for your case it can equal distribution).

Comment: `UILabel` and `UIImageView` are subclasses of `UIView` - you can and them directly to a `UIStackView` - no need to wrap them.

Comment: @AshleyMills `UIStackView` only accepts `UIView`. It accepts `UIImageView` but not `UILabel` hence I wrapped tham in `UIView`.

Comment: This is **incorrect**. You can add any subclass of `UIView` to `a UIStackView`. What happens when you try to add a `UILabel`? What error are you seeing?

Comment: @AshleyMills You were right. I'm not getting any compile error with passing `UILabel` to a `UIStackView`. Not sure why it wasn't accepting `UILabel` at my first attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add some constraints to

```html
 stackView1.alignment = .center
        stackView1.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView1.axis = .vertical
        stackView1.spacing = 10.0
        stackView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: someScrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
        let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView1, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: someScrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)

        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView1, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: someScrollView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 50)

        let alignInCenter = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView1, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: someScrollView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        let alignInCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView1, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: someScrollView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

        someScrollView.addSubview(stackView1)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([alignInCenter,alignInCenterY,leading, trailing, height])
```

and also add some constraints to letters and ImageView

```html
 func createLetters(_ named: [Int: String]) -> [UIView] {
        return named.map { name in
            let letterImage = UIImageView()
            letterImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(name.key)")
            letterImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray


            let letterLabel = UILabel()
            letterLabel.text = name.value
            letterLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

            let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [letterLabel, letterImage])
            stackView.alignment = .center
            stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
            stackView.axis = .horizontal
            let widht = NSLayoutConstraint(item: letterImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
            let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: letterImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widht, height])
            return stackView
        }
    }
```

But I am not sure what axis and what kind of distribution you are looking for in stackView. This code has some of the constraints missing so you have to identify and add them so there is no ambiguity in layouts

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, try adding the `UILabel`s and `UIImageView`s to stack views in a storyboard. Here you can see I'm using horizontal stack views contained in a vertical stack view. From here you can see the constraints you'll need to use to create the same in code.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Update code as:

func createLetters(_ named: [Int: String]) -> [UIView] {
        return named.map { name in
            let letterImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: name.key*10, width: 20, height: 20))
            letterImage.image = UIImage(named: "(name.key)")
             letterImage.backgroundColor = .green

```
        let letterLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: name.key*10, width: 20, height: 20))
        letterLabel.text = name.value
        letterLabel.backgroundColor = .red

        let stackView   = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:name.key*30, width: 100, height: 50))
        stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
        stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
        stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        stackView.spacing   = 16.0

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(letterImage)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(letterLabel)

        return stackView
    }
}
```

This will return 3 stack views as someLetters array count is 3. call it as

```
self.tview.addSubview(createLetters(someLetters)[0])
self.tview.addSubview(createLetters(someLetters)[1])
self.tview.addSubview(createLetters(someLetters)[2])
```

if you to get only one stack view label and image with same code then pass only one parameter.